# How to stop timer after reaching zero?

Tags: javascript

In this http://jsfiddle.net/kuox9ax2/ I have a timer that counts down.

- When it reaches zero, it starts over. It shouldn't do that.
- As JS is asynchronous I can't figure out how to get it to call a function only when it have reached zero.

I have tried to as `return true` in `startTimer()`, but then I run into that JS is asynchronous, so it returns true right away.

Can someone show how to solve these two issues?

```js
function startTimer(duration, display) {
  var timer = duration, minutes, seconds;

  setInterval(function() {
    minutes = parseInt(timer / 60, 10)
    seconds = parseInt(timer % 60, 10);

    minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
    seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;

    display.textContent = minutes + ":" + seconds;

    if (--timer < 0) {
      timer = duration;
    }
  }, 1000);
}

window.onload = function() {
  var time = 5, display = document.querySelector('#time');
  var isDone = startTimer(time, display);

  if (isDone) {
    alert("a");
  }
};
```

```html
<div>Timeout in <span id="time">00:00</span> minutes</div>
```

Comment: You should post some examples or explanations of what you have already tried to show that  you're not asking someone to do your work for you.

Comment: Have you tried to use `setTimeout` instead of `setInterval` - see documentation [here](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp)

Comment: @gus27 Yes, but then I get the issue that it doesn't update every second and only when is finished.

Comment: @DevlshOne Good point. Now added.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Store your interval in a variable and call `clearInterval` when reaching 0. Javascript functions can be passed as parameters, typically named callbacks. Simply pass a function as a parameter and call it when needed.

```js
function startTimer(duration, display, callback) {
  var timer = duration,
    minutes, seconds;

  var myInterval = setInterval(function() {
    minutes = parseInt(timer / 60, 10)
    seconds = parseInt(timer % 60, 10);

    minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
    seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;

    display.textContent = minutes + ":" + seconds;

    if (--timer < 0) {
      timer = duration;
      
      // clear the interal
      clearInterval(myInterval);

      // use the callback
      if(callback) {
          callback();
      }
    }
  }, 1000);
}

window.onload = function() {
  var time = 5,
    display = document.querySelector('#time');
  startTimer(time, display, function() { alert('done'); });
};
```

```html
<div>Timeout in <span id="time">00:00</span> minutes</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`WindowTimers.clearInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/clearInterval)

```js
function startTimer(duration, display) {
  var timer = duration, minutes, seconds;

  var myInterval = setInterval(function() {
    minutes = parseInt(timer / 60, 10)
    seconds = parseInt(timer % 60, 10);

    minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
    seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;

    display.textContent = minutes + ":" + seconds;

    if (--timer < 0) {
      clearInterval(myInterval);
      doneFunction();
    }
  }, 1000);
}

window.onload = function() {
  var time = 5, display = document.querySelector('#time');
  startTimer(time, display);
};

function doneFunction(){
  console.log("done !");
}
```

```html
<div>Timeout in <span id="time">00:00</span> minutes</div>
```

Comment: Did you actually try this? It does not show the alert.

Comment: @trincot I forgot this part of the question. My answer is now updated

Comment: That is one way of solving it, a better pattern is to use callbacks that can be passed into the executing method.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot force an async method to return after the async operation completes - and to do so is an anti pattern.

Instead, you can pass a function to the method to be executed when the async operation finishes. You also need to store a reference to the `setInterval()` and call `clearInterval()` on that when the timer reaches zero. Try this:

```js
function startTimer(duration, display, callback) {
  var timer = duration, minutes, seconds;

  var interval = setInterval(function() {
    var minutes = parseInt(timer / 60, 10)
    var seconds = parseInt(timer % 60, 10);

    display.textContent = ("00" + minutes).slice(-2) + ":" + ("00" + seconds).slice(-2);
    
    if (minutes === 0 && seconds === 0) {
      clearInterval(interval);
      callback && callback();
    }
    timer--;
  }, 1000);
}

window.onload = function() {
  var time = 5, display = document.querySelector('#time');
  
  startTimer(time, display, function() {
    console.log("timer reached zero");
  });
};
```

```html
<div>Timeout in <span id="time">00:00</span> minutes</div>
```