# Timer stop at 0

Tags: javascript

I have this working code and I would like the timer to stop at 0 instead of continuing with negative numbers

```
  function animateValue(id) {
  var obj = document.getElementById(id);
  var current = +localStorage.getItem('counter') || +obj.innerHTML;
  obj.innerHTML = current;
  function decrement(){
    --current;
    obj.innerHTML = current;
    localStorage.setItem('counter', current);
    if(current != 0){
        setTimeout(decrement, (Math.floor(Math.random()*11) + 10) * 1000);
    }
  }
  setTimeout(decrement, (Math.floor(Math.random()*11) + 10) * 2000);
}

animateValue('counter');
```

i tried to add but to no avail

```
if (seconds === 0) {
    stop();
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When using setTimeout do you have to clearTimeout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7391567/when-using-settimeout-do-you-have-to-cleartimeout)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40632567/how-to-stop-timer-after-reaching-zero

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the code inside decrement in an if statement like so:

```
function decrement() {
    if (current > 0) {
        --current;
        obj.innerHTML = current;
        localStorage.setItem('counter', current);
        setTimeout(decrement, (Math.floor(Math.random()*11) + 10) * 1000);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use `setInterval` for it, you can deactivate it with `clearInterval`.

It will work at least that I think

Answer (score 0):

For this bit you tried,

```
   if (seconds === 0) {
    stop();
}
```

Is this not meant to be

```
if (current <= 0) {
    stop(); //I assume you have some code to stop it
}
```